# React - Get the value of an input by clicking on a button

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I need to implement a search button that searches the value of an input. I know how to add an onClick `listener` (is that the name?) to the button so that it `fires` (is that the expresion?) a function.

But within the function, I don't know how to `get` the input value.

Here's what I got:

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const { jobs, loading, error } = useFetchJobs(query, page)

  function handleSearch(e) {
    setQuery(???)
    setPage(1)
  }

  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Here's what I've tried. A line of code I found on google. I get `Error: Function components cannot have string refs`

```
function App() {
  function handleSearch(e) {

    setQuery(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.search).value.trim())
    setPage(1)
  }

  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
      <input type="text" ref="search" ></input>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: you will need to use React Hooks(useState) to get and set the value of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create a `handleChange` on input, and every time the input changes, the state changes... so on you run the `handleSubmit`, you only have to get the state

```
function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  function handleSearch(e) {
    // here you can get the inputValue
     DoWhateverIWantWithSearchValue(inputValue)
  }

  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
      <input type="text" handleChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} ></input>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is not like as `React` code.

React encourage use `useState` and `useCallback` in Functional component. And you need to use `state` and `props` than `ref`

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react"

function App() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const { jobs, loading, error } = useFetchJobs(query, page)

    const handleSearch = useCallback((e) {
        /** You can access query in this function */
        setPage(1)
    },[query])

    const onChangeQuery = useCallback((event)=>{
        setQuery(event.target.value)
    },[])

    return (
        <Container className="my-4">
            <input type="text" value={query} onChange={onChangeQuery} />
            <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>    
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First set the value of the input to `query`(initial value will be null as we set that in `useState`) then on changing the value of the input we set value of the input to `setQuery` using onChange method, now you can use the `query` value to search

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const { jobs, loading, error } = useFetchJobs(query, page)

  function handleSearch(e) {

\\**write your search function here with query value** 
  }

  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
      <input value={query} onChange={(e)=>setQuery(e.target.value)} type="text"></input>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you give the value input his own value? Its like a convention?

Comment: @FábioFialho yeah it is, without setting the value , the change will not show in the input tag

Comment: You can try that

Answer (score 2):

You can create a two-way data bind between the input field and the state to get the value from the input field.

You need to use `value` and `onChange()` listener for this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  console.log(query);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="query"
        className="input"
        placeholder="Search for something"
        value={query}
        onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Search here</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={()=>setSearched(value)}>search</button>
      </div>
      <h1>Search Result: {searched}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```